# Como salvar no tipo numeric no Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Olá, estou usando para salvar o preço de um produto no MYSQL o tipo numeric(9,2) mas no meu sistema estou usando Double e ao imprimir ele aparece R$ 2.2 ao invés de R$ 2.20 que tipo de dado poderia usar para ele pegar todas as casas decimais?

//minha classe Produto com Metodos Getter e Setter

```
public class Produto {
   private Double preco;

    public Double getPreco() {
        return preco;
    }

    public void setPreco(Double preco) {
        this.preco = preco;
    }

}
```

//Método Adicionar

```
public void adiciona(Produto produto) {

        id_conexao = N.Conectar();
        String sql = "insert into produto (nome, preco, unidMedida, imgProduto) values (?,?,?,?)";

        try {

            //PreparedStatement para inserção
            stmt = id_conexao.prepareStatement(sql);

            //setar valores
            stmt.setString(1, produto.getNome());
            stmt.setDouble(2, produto.getPreco());
            stmt.setString(3, produto.getUnidMedida());
            stmt.setBytes(4, produto.getImgProduto());

            //executa
            stmt.execute();
            System.out.println("Salvo");


        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println("ERRO ao inserir produto - " + e);
        } finally {
            N.Desconectar();
        }

    }
```

//Criando objeto para enviar

```
Produto produto = new Produto();

produto.setNome(edtNome.getText().toString());                         
produto.setPreco(Double.parseDouble(edtPreco.getText().toString()));               
produto.setUnidMedida(txtUnidMedida.getText().toString());
```

//Imprimindo objeto na interface Android

```
TextView nome = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
        TextView preco = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtPreco);
        TextView unidMedida = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtUnidMedida);
        //ImageView img_prod = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgProduto);

        nome.setText(elementos.get(position).getNome());
        preco.setText(elementos.get(position).getPreco().toString());
        unidMedida.setText(elementos.get(position).getUnidMedida());
```

Comment: onde está o código que imprime o valor? o problema não está nesse código que você postou, o double é armazenado corretamente no banco, o problema está na hora de exibir ele na tela

Comment: pronto coloquei o código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, em algum lugar do seu código( que você não postou ) você está imprimindo o double direto, exemplos de saída:

```
2.2
1.999999
3.0
```

você quer algo que deixe no formato de dinheiro, Reais.
então deve formatar o Double para ser impresso dessa forma
tem várias formas de fazer isso
ex:

```
double preco = 2.20;
System.out.println( String.format( "%.2f", preco ) );
```

exemplos de saída:

```
2.20
1.99
3.00
```

Comment: Ba resolveu meu problema obrigado.

Comment: poderia marcar como resposta correta? obrigado.

Comment: Sou novo aqui, como faço isso?

Comment: clica no sinal de correto que há no lado da minha resposta. como um 'tick' de certo